# How to express current time in words

Tags: swift, foundation

I am able to get current time, Now I want to output it in words.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
print("hours = \(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
```

**Output**

10:30

**How to get this like -**

It's half past ten

Comment: What should happen on a French system? On an Arabic system?

Comment: I am not getting you @matt

Comment: where have you been stuck at? **[what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)**

Comment: I am unable to find how to convert 10: 30 to grammar explanation, **It's half past ten**

Comment: This is not what *alphabetical order* means.

Comment: FYI - there is nothing provided by Apple for this. You will have to write your own code or find a 3rd party library.

Comment: @matt, holex, Daniel Storm - Please check updated question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @MwcsMac points out in his answer, the key to solving this is `Formatter` (once known as `NSFormatter`), particularly by setting the `.numberStyle` to `.spellOut`.

Although this will pick up the current locale (and thus language), the trouble is that many other languages than English do not use the same "half-past", "quarter-to" terminology - for example, in German 10:30 is "halb elf", literally "half (to) eleven".

Writing code that *assumes* that the locale is English/American is *really bad practice* and will probably get the app rejected if it is offered outside those areas, so the best one could really do is format "10:30" as "ten thirty", "zehn dreißig".

Code with apologies to @MwcsMac:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

func spell(_ number: Int, _ localeID: String) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
    // Specify the locale or you will inherit the current default locale
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeID)
    if let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) {
        // AVOID forced unwrapping at all times!
        return s
    } else {
        return "<Invalid>" // or make return optional and return `nil`
    }
}
spell(hour, "EN") + " " + spell(minute, "EN") // "nineteen thirty-three"
spell(hour, "FR") + " " + spell(minute, "FR") // ""dix-neuf trente-trois"
spell(hour, "AR") + " " + spell(minute, "AR") // "تسعة عشر ثلاثة و ثلاثون"
```

Comment: Building on this code. What if you added `let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode` and then you could have `spell(hour, langStr!) + " " + spell(minutes, langStr!)`?  Which would handle passing the language code.

Comment: Sure - or (as your code does) you could ignore the locale, and it would default to `Locale.current`! I just added it to clarify that locale is important, whether specified or defaulted...

Answer (score 3):

This code will show you that it is possible to achieve the end goal. Keep in mind as stated above you will need create the logic for combinations that you want achieve.

**Swift 3**

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

func spell(_ number: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut // This will convert the number to words.
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))!
}

if minutes == 30 {
    let hourString = spell(hour)
    print("It's half past \(hourString)")
}
```

This could be a way that you would use a range for the time frames.

```
if case 1 ... 14 = minutes {
     let hourString = spell(hour) // This will give your hour in word form
     let minString = spell(minutes) // This will give your minutes in word form
     print("It's \(minString) past \(hourString)")
}
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but you really need to tidy it up. What does `let numberAsNumber = Int(number)` do when `number` is an `Int` already? Why the spurious `let formatter = ` in the `if` clause? What happens if `minutes <= 30`??? And please *comment* what you're doing!

Comment: I don't know anyone that considers all of 15 - 29 minutes past an hour to be "quarter past".